# Can't convert QLineEdit input into float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made an exchange rate program which i could use from the terminal and I'm trying to make an interface for I but I can't turn the QLineEdit input into float.
It gives me this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ..., line 73, in 
    self.buton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pressed(currency1, currency2,input))
  ..., line 79, in pressed
    quantity = float(input)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

```
      self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)

      self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

----



     input=self.lineEdit.text()

----


    self.buton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pressed(currency1, currency2,input))



    def pressed(self,currency1,currency2,input):

        quantity = float(input)

        if currency1 == "EUR":
           self.label.setText("{} EUR = {} {}".format(quantity, currency2, float(self.json_data["rates"][currency2]) * quantity))


        else:
             self.label.setText("{} {} = {} {}".format(quantity, currency1, currency2, float(
                (self.json_data["rates"][currency2] / self.json_data["rates"][currency1])) * quantity))
```

**Here is the full code if needed.**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import requests



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Exchange")
        Form.resize(850, 558)
        self.buton=QtWidgets.QPushButton("Calculate")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 751, 351))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.buton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addStretch()
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)



        self.label.setText("Select currencies and enter the quantity")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        url = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=f79c72f7979f662b465bd28e40efa5cf&format=1"
        response = requests.get(url)
        self.json_data = response.json()
        kurlar=self.json_data["rates"].keys()
        for i in kurlar:
            self.comboBox.addItem(i)
            self.comboBox_2.addItem(i)

        index=self.comboBox.findText("TRY",QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(index)

        currency1=self.comboBox.currentText()
        currency2=self.comboBox_2.currentText()

        input=self.lineEdit.text()



        self.buton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pressed(currency1, currency2,input))



    def pressed(self,currency1,currency2,input):

        quantity = float(input)

        if currency1 == "EUR":
           self.label.setText("{} EUR = {} {}".format(quantity, currency2, float(self.json_data["rates"][currency2]) * quantity))


        else:
             self.label.setText("{} {} = {} {}".format(quantity, currency1, currency2, float(
                (self.json_data["rates"][currency2] / self.json_data["rates"][currency1])) * quantity))


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because you're getting the text from the lineEdit in the beginning  itself that's why it is an empty string you should get the text from lineEdit after pressing the button

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import requests


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Exchange")
        Form.resize(850, 558)
        self.buton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Calculate")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 751, 351))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.buton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addStretch()
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)

        self.label.setText("Select currencies and enter the quantity")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        url = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=f79c72f7979f662b465bd28e40efa5cf&format=1"
        response = requests.get(url)
        self.json_data = response.json()
        kurlar = self.json_data["rates"].keys()
        for i in kurlar:
            self.comboBox.addItem(i)
            self.comboBox_2.addItem(i)

        index = self.comboBox.findText("TRY", QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(index)

        currency1 = self.comboBox.currentText()
        currency2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()


        self.buton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pressed(currency1, currency2))

    def pressed(self, currency1, currency2):
        # getting the text from the lineEdit after pressing the button
        quantity = float(self.lineEdit.text())

        if currency1 == "EUR":
            self.label.setText(
                "{} EUR = {} {}".format(quantity, currency2, float(self.json_data["rates"][currency2]) * quantity))


        else:
            self.label.setText("{} {} = {} {}".format(quantity, currency1, currency2, float(
                (self.json_data["rates"][currency2] / self.json_data["rates"][currency1])) * quantity))

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```